# How to create web component using vue-cli

Tags: web-component, vue-cli-3

i want to create custom web component, so i can reuse this component to another project, it's work locally when i run `yarn serve`

[image]

and then i publish it to npm, but when i import it to another vue project i got this error

[image]

Github Page : https://github.com/point-red/vue-point-table

```
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null"

found in

---> <PointTable>
       <App>
         <Root>
```

anyone can help ? i don't know where is the mistake

Comment: Not sure but I see a race condition, `this.isShow = false;` but before it could be true you use the uuid to look for the dom element using getElementById which it wont find due to the v-`if="isShow"` in the view but your not checking for failure to find it, hence the errors

Comment: The link to the github page is giving 404.

Using md-mode="fixed-last" in a app of mine was causing the same warning reported by you. Don't know if this was you case...